# How to hide item in Ext menu base on condition when load

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, menu

i am trying to hide an item in Ext.menu.Menu base on condition but, i cannot find the trigger load event of menu. Can you give me advice.

```
//var lala //= 1 2 or 3

var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        id: 'mainMenu',
        items: [

            {
                text: 'I like Ext',
                checked: true,       // condition 1
                checkHandler: onItemCheck
            }, {
               text: 'Choose a Date',
               iconCls: 'calendar',
               menu: dateMenu // <-- condition 2
           },{
               text: 'Choose a Color',
               menu: colorMenu // <-- condition 3
           }
        ]
    });
```

Example: only show checkbox in menu if lala = 1. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `afterRender` listener on menu items:

```
{
    text: 'Choose a Date',
    iconCls: 'calendar',
    menu: dateMenu // <-- condition 2
    listeners: {
        afterRender: function() {
            if (lala == 2)
                this.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, but if you do this, it actually hide the whole Menu.

Comment: You have to set the `afterrender` listener in the menu item, not the menu itself. Also, to avoid confusion with `this`, the component with the listener is (in most cases) passed as the first argument, so you can call `afterrender: function(menuItem) { menuItem.hide(); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
//var lala //= 1 2 or 3

var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        id: 'mainMenu',
        items: [

            {
                text: 'I like Ext',
                checked: true,       // condition 1
                hidden : lala == 1 ? true:false,
                checkHandler: onItemCheck
            }, {
               text: 'Choose a Date',
               iconCls: 'calendar',
               hidden : lala == 2 ? true:false,
               menu: dateMenu // <-- condition 2
           },{
               text: 'Choose a Color',
               hidden : lala == 3 ? true:false,
               menu: colorMenu // <-- condition 3
           }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: There is no need for `booleanStatement ? true : false`, since it already equals `true` or `false`. You can just use `hidden: lala == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

From your code `//var lala //= 1 2 or 3`, I presume, you know the value of `lala` when creating the menu. All you need to do then is set the items of the menu, that you want.

Something along the lines of:

```
var menuItems = [];

if (lala === 1) {
    menuItems.push({
        text: 'I like Ext',
        checked: true,       // condition 1
        checkHandler: onItemCheck
    });
}
else if (lala === 2) {
    menuItems.push({
        text: 'Choose a Date',
        iconCls: 'calendar',
        menu: dateMenu // <-- condition 2
    });
}
else if (lala === 3) {
    menuItems.push({
        text: 'Choose a Color',
        menu: colorMenu // <-- condition 3
    })
}

var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    id: 'mainMenu',
    items: menuItems
});
```

You keep talking about 'load'. Your example menu does not have any store, so it does not actually load.

However, if you need to change the menu on the fly, when some store loads (or some other event is fired), you can do it like this:

```
// Set all menu items in menu
var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    id: 'mainMenu',
    items: [
        {
            text: 'I like Ext',
            itemId: 'lala1', // Item ID to find the component on the fly
            hidden: lala !== 1, // if lala is already initialized
            //hidden: true, // if lala is not initialized
            checked: true,       // condition 1
            checkHandler: onItemCheck
        }, 
        {
            text: 'Choose a Date',
            itemId: 'lala2', // Item ID to find the component on the fly
            hidden: lala !== 2, // If lala is already initialized
            //hidden: true, // if lala is not initialized
            iconCls: 'calendar',
            menu: dateMenu // <-- condition 2
        },
        {
            text: 'Choose a Color',
            itemId: 'lala3', // Item ID to find the component on the fly
            hidden: lala !== 3, // If lala is already initialized
            //hidden: true, // if lala is not initialized
            menu: colorMenu // <-- condition 3
        }
    ]
});

// Your store load (or any other event of your choosing)
yourStore.on({
    load: function() {
        var newLala = getLalaSomehow(); // Get lala the way you do

        // Get menu items by the item IDs set previously
        var menuItemLala1 = menu.down('#lala1');
        var menuItemLala2 = menu.down('#lala2');
        var menuItemLala3 = menu.down('#lala3');

        // Show/hide menu items based on a condition
        menuItemLala1.setVisible(newLala === 1); // Only show when lala is 1
        menuItemLala2.setVisible(newLala === 2); // Only show when lala is 2
        menuItemLala3.setVisible(newLala === 3); // Only show when lala is 3
    }
});
```

In the example above, I am using [`setVisible`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item-method-setVisible) method, which shows the component when the passed argument is `true` and hides it, if it's `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the correct way is that trigger before Ext Menu build. Or else the afterrender on run once.